# Kunneth formula proof doubt, and natural transformation

Tags: homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, natural-transformations

I have been reading MacLane's Book on Homology and I have a doubt in the proof of the Kunneth Formula[image]

In $10.5)$ he he says that $\bigoplus D_{m+1}\otimes H_q(L) \cong H_{n+1}(D \otimes L)$, and i cant quite see this is true, we know that since evey $D_{m}$ is flat we have that $D_m \otimes H_q(L) \cong H_q(D_m \otimes L)$ but i dont see how this gives us the rest, i guess my question is why is $\bigoplus H_q(D_{m+1} \otimes L) \cong H_{n+1}(D \otimes L)$?Is this true because of the way we defined the tensor product of complexes, and because the direct sum commutes with homology?

Also i am a little bit confused on how $10.6)$ proves that $\beta$ is natural, so any advice would be helpfull [image].

Thanks in advance.